# ASP.NET Core 8 : app.UseStaticFiles() pipeline execution order

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-8.0

I'm trying a simple ASP.NET Core 8 web app. Created a `/wwwroot/error.html`.

When requesting `/error.html` in the browser, it works, no problem at all.

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.Run();
```

Then I've added a `.MapGet` **after** the `app.UseStaticFiles()`, and when request `/error.html` in the browser, it is not working, it renders "Hello World!"

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.MapGet("/{*path}", () => "Hello World!");

app.Run();
```

When using static files middleware before any route mapping, if the requested file is found, it must serve it, or not?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add explicit `UseRouting` call (if it is not called it is added by default somewhere at start of pipeline and you will have your catch-all route to have a precedence):

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.MapGet("/{*path}", () => "Hello World!");
```

Comment: Perfect! Placing app.UseRouting(); after the .UseStaticFiles() did the trick!

Comment: Can you expand on the reasons for this?

Comment: @ChadT I'm not ready to dive deep into it ATM (maybe later) but basically this is a consequence of importance of [middleware order in request handling pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) in combination with [catch-all parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#route-templates) which will greedily match any route.

Answer (score 0):

The order of middleware execution matters in ASP.NET Core.

In your case, `app.UseStaticFiles();` is placed before `app.MapGet("/{*path}", () => "Hello World!");` in your middleware pipeline.

When a request for `/error.html` comes in, it first goes through the `UseStaticFiles` middleware. Since the file exists in the `wwwroot` folder, the static file middleware will handle the request and serve the file.

If you want the `MapGet` middleware to handle the request before the static files middleware, you can change the order of middleware registration:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/{*path}", () => "Hello World!");

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.Run();
```

By placing `app.MapGet` before `app.UseStaticFiles`, you are saying, "first, try to handle the request using this `MapGet` middleware, and if it doesn't match, then let the static files middleware handle it."

Comment: If this would do anything it would make things worse =) `app.MapGet` - does not add a middleware but adds route/endpoint map.